# Adding Custom Header to sap.m.Dialog

Tags: sapui5

I want to add custom header with buttons to my `sap.m.Dialog`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Dialog/aggregations) you can see that `sap.m.Dialog` has an aggregation `customHeader` which takes any "Bar-Interface" (currently `sap.m.Bar` or `sap.m.Toolbar`).

For example like this:

```
<Dialog>
    <customHeader>
        <Bar>
            <contentLeft>
                <Button />
            </contentLeft>
            <contentMiddle>
                <Title text="Dialog Title" />
            </contentMiddle>
        </Bar>
    </customHeader>
    <!-- Content here -->
</Dialog>
```